# Internet explorer 11 Angularjs + NodeJS + Mongoose issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angularjs

I'm developping my website with Angularjs framework in the front end , nodejs backend and mongoose to persist my data into a MongoDB database.

In firefox RS v.24 and chrome all is ok, when i add a user into the database, this new user is displayed automatically into my list grid.

But in IE 11 it doesn't until i close the browser and open it back .

when i add a new profile, i do the following in my Controller:

```
    $scope.AddProfil = function() {

    $http.post('/ajouterProfils', $scope.profil)
        .success(function(data) {

            $scope.profilFlag = data; /*unit tests*/
            $scope.lastDocId = data._id;
            $scope.ajouterProfilTag($scope.lastDocId);
            $scope.profil = {};
            $scope.tagStyles.length = 0;
            $scope.tagStyles = [];
            $scope.colorList = {};
            angular.element($('.shown-text-add').text($('.shown-text-add').text()));
            angular.element($('.shown-text-add').css('font-family', ''));
            angular.element($('.shown-text-add').css('font-size', ''));
            angular.element($('.shown-text-add').css('line-height', ''));
            angular.element($('.shown-text-add').css('font-weight', ''));
            setTimeout( function(){$('#addPanel').show();} );
            setTimeout( function(){$('#addPanel').fadeOut();}, 2500);




        });
};
```

in my DAO, i have this :

```
    /**
 * Add a profile
 */
exports.createProfile = function(req, res) {
  var profile = new Profil(req.body);

  profile.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.send('users/signup', {
        errors: err.errors,
        profile: profile
      });
    } else {

      res.jsonp(profile);
    }
  });
};
```

Any ideas ? feedbacks ?

Comment: Without any code it's impossible to try and help.

Comment: You should manipulate the DOM using directives rather than doing it in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, use [directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and [data binding](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding) rather than DOM manipulation.
Clearly this is your problem as you say the data is there when you reload the browser, so the issue is not with the server side components.